# Google analytics - track if DIV loaded with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a website with a contact form. Now i want to track if the form was successfully sent by checking if the confirmation message is loaded (the mesage is within a div with the class"gform_confirmation_message").

I tried the following but nothing happens:

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('.gform_confirmation_message').ready(function(e){
        ga.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Completions', 'Form_'+$(this).attr('title')+'_'+location.href]); 
    });
});
```

I thought "ready" is the right way to track if an object is loaded?

Comment: I think (and the jQuery documentation seems to be with me on this) that ready refers to the DOM, not to any object (afaik there is no general observer for DOM changes in jQuery, this has been asked a few times on SO). You should place the tracking call in the function that loads the confirmation div.

Answer (score 0):

Now this works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".gform_confirmation_message").ready(function() {
        ga('send','event', 'Herbstaktion', 'Gravity Form abgesendet');
    });
});
```

"ready" seems to work here. Problem above was that the google analytics code was a mixture of old "_gaq" and new "ga" style.